# Use a variable defined in express "app.get" in socket.io "connection"

Tags: node.js, express, variables, socket.io

I connect to a socket.io namespace using Express app.get. **I send a parameter 'param'** with the URL accessing the namespace. I want to access the parameter from outside the app.get scope. I tried with global variables (not the best choice, I know) :

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  foo = req.query.param;
  console.log(foo);
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/template.html'); 
});
```

`Console.log` displays what I want.

However, if I do this later in the code :

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(foo);
});
```

The error says "**foo is not defined**". I thought it is global because I did not use 'var'.

I also tried app.set and app.get but without more success.

**How can I access the parameter I got from the URL inside io.connect ?**

Thank you.

Comment: What about if `io.sockets.on('connection'` happens before `app.get` then it makes sense that foo is undefined.

Comment: Well, as far as I know, app.get happens first, as it does the routing. I tried to create a variable in 'connection' first and call it in app.get, but it is undefined as well.

Comment: I have found the answer. In fact, its says "undefined" only when I start the Node.js server, but hasn't received any URL yet, so the parameter do not exist.